# PL/sql function return an error of many rows

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

This function is returning only the VAC_NAME (but not the list of these names)

```
create or replace function FCT_VAC(NO_VAC in number)
return varchar2
is
V_lNAME varchar2(30);
begin
    select u.UTI_NAME ||' '|| u.UTI_L_NAME into V_lNAME  
    from USER_TAB u
      join DEAL_TAB d on u.USERNAME = d.USERNAME
;

return V_lNAME;
end FCT_VAC_NAME;
/
set serveroutput on;
select FCT_VAC_NAME(3) as Vacantion_Name from dual;
```

but if I will simple select

```
 select u.UTI_NAME, u.UTI_L_NAME  
 from USER_TAB u 
    join DEAL_TAB d on u.USERNAME = d.USERNAME
;
```

It works as expected, what is the problem of function?

Comment: Because you can only return one (out) parameter at a time within a function. In your case there are two concatenated. To return them seperately, you need a procedure.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: or a pipelined function

Answer (score 0):

Query returns two (or more) rows; they can't fit into a scalar `v_lname varchar2(30)` variable.

Question is: what result do you expect? Only one value? Then make sure that query returns it; `WHERE` clause might help (especially as you pass a parameter but never use it), e.g.

```
select u.UTI_NAME ||' '|| u.UTI_L_NAME 
into V_lNAME  
from USER_TAB u
  join DEAL_TAB d on u.USERNAME = d.USERNAME
where u.no_vac = p_no_vac;                      --> this
```

Note that I've renamed parameter; I don't know whether any of those tables contain `no_vac` column, but - if it does - you'd better use a different name for the parameter. One option is to prefix it with `p_`.

Otherwise, rewrite the function so that it returns *something else* (custom type, table, whatever).

Comment: It must return value from u.UTI_NAME concatinated with u.UTI_L_NAME, so I can say, it need to return two values merged in one

Comment: That's not the problem. I explained what is; query returns more than one **row**.

Comment: Ok, what to I need to remove from function, so it will return 1 row?

Comment: I told you already. Add the WHERE clause. Do you not read what people say?